# multiple dist directories occur in requests when aurelia bundle is deployed

Tags: gulp, systemjs, jspm, aurelia

I was trying to deploy my aurelia application using gulp. Once deployed however I see all the css and js files being requested with multiple dist directories in the request path. I don't quite know why this is occurring.

This is one of the warning message in the chrome console 
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

"
    http://integration.mcc.gto.intranet.db.com/mcc-gui/mu/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/dist/styles/bootstrap-theme-3.3.2.min.css"

This is my bundles section in the gulp build tasks:

```
{
  "bundles": {
    "dist/app-build": {
      "includes": [
        "[**/*.js]",
        "**/*.html!text",
        "**/*.css!text"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": true,
        "rev": false
      }
    },
    "dist/aurelia": {
      "includes": [
        "aurelia-framework",
        "aurelia-bootstrapper",
        "aurelia-event-aggregator",
        "aurelia-fetch-client",
        "aurelia-router",
        "aurelia-animator-css",
        "aurelia-templating-binding",
        "aurelia-polyfills",
        "aurelia-templating-resources",
        "aurelia-templating-router",
        "aurelia-loader-default",
        "aurelia-history-browser",
        "aurelia-logging-console",
        "aurelia-pal-browser",
        "aurelia-templating-binding",
        "bootstrap",
        "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text",
        "bootstrap-tour",
        "d3",
        "fetch",
        "font-awesome",
        "jquery",
        "lodash",
        "moment"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": false,
        "rev": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you try to make a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, if you'll provide a downloadable example of the issue, it will help us to figure out the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I've built the skeleton navigation project  but with build files, config.js and package.json that mirror my original project . It's present here : https://github.com/tkmandanna/skeleton-esnext 

I hope this help since I could upload the original source code as that was from my company's project.